# Ajax jsonp missing ; error

Tags: ajax, json

I am near a solution to get json data, just get the error :
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

My json data look like this :

{"custom1":"","dateOfBirth":null,"custom2":"","custom3":"","custom4":"","custom5":""}

I am using jsonp. this solved my problem with CORS (Cross-origin request blocked)
In the debugger i can see the data in the NET.
How close i am?
Som get me the last push to resolve my problem??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://myurl/api/getUser/22?_key=123456789',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        //contentType: "application/jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
                              $('#badge').append(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your ajax response type to `jsonp` instead of `json`.

Like

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

You can read more about it in [`jquery docs on $.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also as I can see, the `result` variable that you are trying to append in the success callback is not declared & inititalized anywhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: Changed te json to the jsonp with the same problem ( forget to adjust it)